# Is XSS possible if I insert untrusted data into an quoted HTML attribute and HTML encode the " sign?

Tags: xss

If I insert untrusted data in a HTML attribute like this:

```
<img src="http://www.mydomain/<%untrusted_data%>">
```

and if I HTML encode the `"` sign in the untrusted data, is this particular code snipped fully protected against XSS? I know that I should be careful not to allow the user to insert the whole URL because then they could insert `javascript:alert()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if the attribute is double quoted and you are encoding the double quote character, then it shouldn't be possible to escape from the quoted attribute.

However, I would also encode the `&` symbol because that can be used to start an encoded character in itself.

The [HTML5 spec states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-double-quoted):

> A double-quoted attribute value is specified by providing the
>   following parts in exactly the following order:
>
> - an attribute name
> - zero or more space characters
> - a single "=" character
> - zero or more space characters
> - a single """ character
> - an attribute
>     value
> - a """ character
>
> In addition to the general requirements for
>   attribute values, a double-quoted attribute value has the following
>   restriction:
>
> must not contain any literal """ characters